# What's the best way to create "vertical rules" in CSS, and where can I read more about it?

Tags: css, templates, layout, user-interface

I have a main content region in the center of my page which is 660px wide.  I want to separate it into two 330px-wide divs.  What's the best way to go about this?  Should I be using px?  Do you have any place that I can read more about a good approach or two?

Comment: Do you mean to create vertical columns, like in magazines or newspapers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put two divs inside of your center div, float one to the left and one to the right. Clear your floats (http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) by adding 'overflow:hidden' to the container.

This will effectively split your column into two. You can specific the dimensions of the interior divs in px, or %, whichever you prefer.

Here is a working example: http://tinkerbin.com/MGjJBDS4

Comment: Nathan, This is really great.  I tried full-page zooming, and I like how it works with that, also.  Thank you.

Comment: Be careful not to set an explicit height on a container if you're using overflow hidden to contain floats.

Comment: Good point, if you run into problems with overflow:hidden, use the clearfix hack: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/